# Bad type deduction when passing overloaded function pointer and its arguments

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, template-meta-programming, type-deduction

I'm trying to provide a wrapper around `std::invoke` to do the work of deducing the function type even when the function is overloaded.
(I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60575881/is-there-a-generic-way-to-pass-pointers-of-overloaded-methods-that-requires-less) yesterday for the variadic and method pointer  version).

When the function has one argument this code (C++17) works as expected under normal overload conditions:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename ReturnType, typename ... Args>
using FunctionType = ReturnType (*)(Args...);

template <typename S, typename T>
auto Invoke (FunctionType<S, T> func, T arg)
{   
    return std::invoke(func, arg);
}

template <typename S, typename T>
auto Invoke (FunctionType<S, T&> func, T & arg)
{   
    return std::invoke(func, arg);
}

template <typename S, typename T>
auto Invoke (FunctionType<S, const T&> func, const T & arg)
{
    return std::invoke(func, arg);
}

template <typename S, typename T>
auto Invoke (FunctionType<S, T&&> func, T && arg)
{   
    return std::invoke(func, std::move(arg));
}
```

Reducing the code bloat is obviously needed for more input arguments, but that's a separate problem.

If the user has overloads differing only by const/references, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

void Foo (int &)
{
    std::cout << "(int &)" << std::endl;
}

void Foo (const int &)
{
    std::cout << "(const int &)" << std::endl;
}

void Foo (int &&)
{
    std::cout << "(int &&)" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    Foo(num);
    Invoke(&Foo, num);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    Foo(0);
    Invoke(&Foo, 0);
}
```

Then `Invoke` deduces the function incorrectly, with g++ output:

> (int &)
>   (const int &)
>
> (int &&)
>   (const int &)

And clang++:

> (int &)
>   (const int &)
>
> (int &&)
>   (int &&)

(Thanks to geza for pointing out that clang's outputs were different).

So `Invoke` has undefined behaviour.

I suspect that metaprogramming would be the way to approach this problem. Regardless, is it possible to handle the type deduction correctly at the `Invoke` site?

Comment: What is the expected output?  Is it (int&) (int&&)?

Comment: @L.F., Yep. Those are the outputs of Foo, so they should also be the output of Invoke.

Comment: For me, clang gives a different result: it prints `(int &&)` twice for the second case.

Comment: @geza, Actually, it's the same for me too. I obviously made a mistake. I'll fix it. thank you. Clearly the Invoke is providing undefined behaviour.

Comment: It must have something to do with `S` argument deduction. Try to comment out the `const T &` version of `Invoke` and notice the error. Also if the argument is provided explicitly (`Invoke<void>(&Foo, num)`) the correct version is called.

Comment: @aparpara, you're right! I didn't expect the return type to be causing the problem given that the return types are all the same in this example. As for removing `const T&`, that's just avoiding the problem without solving it.

Comment: Here's a theory for the first case: when the compiler considers the non-const `Invoke`, it can instantiate it with both the const and non-const `Foo`. And it doesn't check that the return type (`S`) is the same for both, so it says that it cannot deduce `S`. So it ignores this template. While instantiating the const `Invoke` can be done only with the const `Foo`, so it can deduce `S` in this case. Hence the compiler uses this template.

Comment: I don't know what's exactly happening and, above all, who's right between g++ and clang++ but... seems to me that you're ignoring that the `&&` reference of the argument of the `Foo()` function is a completely different kind of reference (a r-value reference) compared to the `&&` for the `arg` of `Invoke` (that is a reference of a template value, so is a forwarding reference).

Comment: @max66, I don't understand what you mean. Why do you think that `Invoke` doesn't take that into account?

Comment: First of all, because you use (inside the `&&` version of `Invoke()`) `std::move()` instead of `std::forward`; second, because seems to me (maybe I'm wrong) that your code is based on the idea that a `T && arg` is ever a `T &&` (in a template function).

Comment: @max66, okay, I think that I see you point, although I'm not sure that I agree about `std::move`, my understanding was (correct or not) that any `Bar(T&&)` input function would be deduced as a `Bar (T&)` if the input was an lvalue. If you replace the main with the following code, it behaves like I expected in g++, but don't compile in clang++: `template <typename T> void Bar (T && t) { Foo(std::forward<T>(t)); } int main() { int num; Bar(num); Invoke<void>(&Bar, num); }`

Comment: @Elliott - Frankly, I don't know what's exactly happening (I have big troubles understanding perfect forwarding details) but it seems to me that you're right when you say " any `Bar(T&&)` input function would be deduced as a `Bar (T&)` if the input was an lvalue". So if you use `std::move()` over a l-value, you (potentially) make a disaster: inside the function you can depredate the function when externally is expected that remain valid.

Comment: @max66, what I meant is because if the `Bar(T&&)` is deduced to `Bar(int&)`, say, because of an int lvalue call, I thought that when you do the `int x; Invoke(&Bar, x)` that it would call `Invoke (FunctionType<S, T&>, T&)`. That's what happens with g++ (using my code from my previous comment, and putting a print in the invokes), but sadly this causing a compile error for clang++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Theory

For **each** function template `Invoke`, the template argument deduction (that must succeed for overload resolution to consider it) considers **each** `Foo` to see whether it can deduce however many template parameters (here, two) for the **one** function parameter (`func`) involved.  The overall deduction can succeed only if exactly one `Foo` matches (because otherwise there is no way to deduce `S`).  (This was more or less stated in the comments.)

The first (“by value”) `Invoke` never survives: it can deduce from any of the `Foo`s.  Similarly, the second (“non-`const` reference”) overload accepts the first two `Foo`s.  Note that these apply **regardless** of the other argument to `Invoke` (for `arg`)!

The third (`const T&`) overload selects the corresponding `Foo` overload and deduces `T`=`int`; the last does the same thing with the last overload (where `T&&` is a normal rvalue reference), and therefore rejects lvalue arguments despite its **universal** reference (which deduces `T` as `int&` (or `const int&`) in that case and conflicts with `func`’s deduction).

## Compilers

If the argument for `arg` is an rvalue (and, as usual, isn’t const), both plausible `Invoke` overloads succeed at deduction, and the `T&&` overload should win (because it binds an rvalue reference to an **rvalue**).

For the case from the comments:

```
template <typename U>
void Bar (U &&);
int main() {
  int num;
  Invoke<void>(&Bar, num);
}
```

No deduction takes place from `&Bar` since a function template is involved, so `T` is successfully deduced (as `int`) in every case.  Then, deduction happens **again** for each case to identify the `Bar` specialization (if any) to use, deducing `U` as *fail*, `int&`, `const int&`, and `int&` respectively.  The `int&` cases are identical and plainly better, so the call is ambiguous.

So **Clang** is right here.  (But there’s no “undefined behavior” here.)

## Solution

I don’t have a general answer for you; since certain parameter types can accept multiple value-category/const-qualification pairs, it’s not going to be easy to emulate overload resolution correctly in all such cases.  There have been proposals to reify overload sets in one way or another; you might consider one of the current techniques along those lines (like a **generic lambda** per target function name).